# Update multiple labels with values from a dictionary?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary, random

I'm trying to make an app that will select an index at random, something like `0-1000` and then print the key, value, and link of the selected number to three seperate labels on the iPhone simulator.

So from my example, I want to randomly select `"0"` or `"1"` and if for instance `"1"` was chosen; then the key, value, and link information would each be printed to three  separate labels on the simulator. The following is what I've been working on in playgrounds. Is there a better way to go about this?

```
var spDictionary: [String: [String:String]] = [

    "0": ["key": "AMZN", "value": "AMAZON", "link": "yahoo"],
    "1": ["key": "AAPL", "value": "APPLE", "link": "yahoo2"],

]
```

And for the random aspect I think it would be something like this but I'm not sure? Sorry for the newbie question.

```
let randomIndex: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(spDictionary.count)))`
```

Comment: the _model_ looks reasonable to me.

Comment: Using tuples a tuples? just another approach `let sp:[(String, String,String)] = [("AAPL", "APPLE", "yahoo2") ,("AMZN", "AMAZON", "yahoo")] `

Comment: @TomCobo Apple states: *Tuples are useful for temporary groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures*

Comment: Thanks @vadian :) I though it was for temporary use. Nice answer!

Answer (score 2):

Even for small data structures it's worth it to create a custom class or struct

```
struct Data {
  let key : String
  let value : String
  let link : String
}
```

Create an object

```
let data = Data(key: "AMZN", value: "AMAZON", link: "yahoo")
```

Get a property

```
let link = data.link
```

and you can declare your dictionary

```
var spDictionary : [String: Data] = ...
```